# Facebook Canvas URL-bound Updates Not Reflected On apps.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

A **Facebook Canvas URL**'s source has been updated with **Open Graph protocol meta elements** and linted (no problems). Here's what happens once the changes are published:

- Accessing the canvas URL directly: Open Graph *changes ARE reflected* in the source, as expected.
- Posting the apps.facebook.com "Canvas Page" URL (which points to the remote Canvas URL) on one's wall: The Open Graph *changes ARE NOT reflected*. That is, no image, title, description, et. al.
- If the Canvas Page URL is *slightly* modified (e.g., appended with "index.html" or "#") before posting to one's wall, the *changes ARE reflected*. Just not with the base URL.
- Using http-equiv "no-cache" meta in the source page has *no effect*.

Q: Is there some way to force something along the lines of a cache clear on the apps.facebook.com side, for the base Canvas URL?

Other thoughts:

- No FBML/XFBML is in use.
- Editing the app settings in various ways does not appear to help.
- Can't rename the Canvas page at this point, as the app is now in production.
- Can't append the Canvas URL with anything, as it must remain a directory.
- Renaming the Canvas page URL to use another path doesn't help either.

UPDATE: I see I'm not the only one. Hmm ... plundering the FB Bugzilla vaults. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=329599#p329599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filed with [Facebook Bugzilla](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16321). Later confirmed as a share scraper bug and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the canvas url to the linter it will refresh the cache. If you post some exact urls I can look at it furthur

Comment: That's the thing: **"A Facebook *Canvas URL*'s source has been updated with Open Graph protocol meta elements and *linted*."** However, I should have updated this Q. Turns out this was confirmed as a share scraper bug by Facebook and fixed. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16321